# How to read a csv file and then find out if a particular field in the file contains valid utf-8 characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a case in which i am supposed to read a row inside a csv file and then try to find out if the first column in that row has valid utf-8 characters.

Below is a small sample data inside the csv file i have:

```
Pension Roob,"68233 Kertzmann Mountains Apt. 057, Swiftburgh, NY 18633"
ࠀabaa,"AECS layout main road"
Motel One,"23 Parkstad Germany"
```

I was expecting the second line to give an error but it is not happening.

Below is my Python code for doing that :

```
import csv

def is_valid_utf_8(word):
    try:
        check = word.encode('utf-8')
        print(check)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
    return True


with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in rows:
        if len(row) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            if not is_valid_utf_8(row[0]):
                print(f"{row} has something wrong")
```

Is my way of checking for non UTF-8 characters right?

Or is the data sample that i am using is wrong.

Can someone please throw some light.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of an invalid utf-8 character? Maybe you meant *ASCII* character?

Comment: I have no idea really. Just wondering how do i test my code. I dont even know if the code is right or if the data i am using for testing is wrong

Comment: We can't help you if you have no idea what you want.

Comment: As i said i need to check if the first column contains valid utf-8 characters. But i am not finding many examples online of non utf-8 characters. So i dont have much test data as well. Is my code right ? Is this the right way to test.

Comment: Python doesn't even support invalid utf-8 characters, because python stores strings as utf-8. You should research what utf-8 is if you want to work with it. Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

If you want to check whether the string is convertible, you should use *ascii*, instead of *utf-8*. A fix on your `is_valid_utf_8` method, which is `is_valid_ascii`.

This way you get the coveted error and it checks what you would like to.

```python
def is_valid_ascii(word):
    try:
        print(word)
        check = word.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my understanding of UTF-8 and ascii is very poor. Is it not possible to test for UTF-8 instead ?